# Aligning centered text inside of flexbox

Tags: html, css

How do I align divs centered within flexbox with `align-items: center;` so the text is aligned with some vertical baseline?

Currently: [image]

Desired effect:
[image]

**Current code**:
https://codepen.io/InsaneZulol/pen/JjLgaWa

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the content inside another div:

```css
.specs_table {
  /* We first create a flex layout context */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  /* Then we define how is distributed the remaining space */
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  /* We first create a flex layout context */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  /* Then we define how is distributed the remaining space */
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-item.group-name {
  color: green;
}

.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 3em;
  border: solid 5px green;
  align-items: center;
}

.key_value_pair {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}

.specs-sheet-keyname {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 0.3em;
}

.specs-sheet-value {
  font-size: 0.2em;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="specs_table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-item group-name">
      Battery
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="aligner">
        <div class="key_value_pair">
          <span class="specs-sheet-keyname"> Capacity: </span>
          <span class="specs-sheet-value"> {capacity} </span>
        </div>
        <div class="key_value_pair">
          <span class="specs-sheet-keyname"> Cell Conf.: </span>
          <span class="specs-sheet-value"> {configuration} </span>
        </div>
        <div class="key_value_pair">
          <span class="specs-sheet-keyname"> Cell Conf.: </span>
          <span class="specs-sheet-value"> {configuration} </span>
        </div>
        <div class="key_value_pair">
          <span class="specs-sheet-keyname"> Cell Number: </span>
          <span class="specs-sheet-value"> {configuration} </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the flex item with the list, you would have to wrap the items in a container so that the container is flexed center but not the individual rows.

```css
.specs_table {
  /* We first create a flex layout context */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  /* Then we define how is distributed the remaining space */
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  /* We first create a flex layout context */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  /* Then we define how is distributed the remaining space */
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-item.group-name {
  color: green;
}

.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 3em;
  border: solid 5px green;
  align-items: center;
}

.key_value_pair {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}

.specs-sheet-keyname {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 0.3em;
}

.specs-sheet-value {
  font-size: 0.2em;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="specs_table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-item group-name">
      Battery
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="key_value_pair">
        <span class="specs-sheet-keyname"> Capacity: </span>
        <span class="specs-sheet-value"> {capacity} </span>
      </div>
      <div class="key_value_pair">
        <span class="specs-sheet-keyname"> Cell Conf.: </span>
        <span class="specs-sheet-value"> {configuration} </span>
      </div>
      <div class="key_value_pair">
        <span class="specs-sheet-keyname"> Cell Conf.: </span>
        <span class="specs-sheet-value"> {configuration} </span>
      </div>
      <div class="key_value_pair">
        <span class="specs-sheet-keyname"> Cell Number: </span>
        <span class="specs-sheet-value"> {configuration} </span>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```